# Parsing pseudo-HTML/XML logfiles into a data frame (Symantec Altiris) [R]

Tags: html, r, parsing, logging, altiris

I've been asked to help parse some log files for a Symantec application (Altiris) and they were delivered to me in a pseudo-HTML/XML format. I've managed to use `readLines()` and `grepl()` to get the logs into a decent character vector format and clean out the junk, but can't get it into a data-frame.

As of right now, an entry looks something like this (since I can't post real data), all in a character vector with structure `chr[1:312]`:

```
[310] "<severity='4', hostname='computername125', source='PackageDownload', module='herpderp.dll', process='masterP.exe', pid='234' >"
```

I've had no luck with XML parsing and it does look more like HTML to me, and when I tried `htmlTreeParse(x)` I just ended up with a massive pyramid of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with pseudo-XML, it's probably best to define the parsing rules yourself. I like `stringr` and `dplyr` for stuff like this.

Here's a two-element vector (instead of 312 in your case):

```
vec <- c(
  "<severity='4', hostname='computername125', source='PackageDownload', module='herpderp.dll', process='masterP.exe', pid='234' >",
  "<severity='5', hostname='computername126', source='PackageDownload', module='herpderp.dll', process='masterP.exe', pid='235' >"
)
```

Convert it to a `data.frame` object:

```
df <- data.frame(vec, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And select out your data based on their character index positions, relative to the positions of your variables of interest:

```
require(stringr)
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    severityStr = str_locate(vec, "severity")[, "start"],
    hostnameStr = str_locate(vec, "hostname")[, "start"],
    sourceStr = str_locate(vec, "source")[, "start"],
    moduleStr = str_locate(vec, "module")[, "start"],
    processStr = str_locate(vec, "process")[, "start"],
    pidStr = str_locate(vec, "pid")[, "start"],
    endStr = str_locate(vec, ">")[, "start"],
    severity = substr(vec, severityStr + 10, hostnameStr - 4),
    hostname = substr(vec, hostnameStr + 10, sourceStr - 4),
    source = substr(vec, sourceStr + 8, moduleStr - 4),
    module = substr(vec, moduleStr + 8, processStr - 4),
    process = substr(vec, processStr + 9, pidStr - 4),
    pid = substr(vec, pidStr + 5, endStr - 3)) %>%
  select(severity, hostname, source, module, process, pid)
```

Here's the resulting data frame:

```
  severity        hostname          source       module     process pid
1        4 computername125 PackageDownload herpderp.dll masterP.exe 234
2        5 computername126 PackageDownload herpderp.dll masterP.exe 235
```

This solution is robust enough to handle string inputs of different lengths. For example, it would read `pid` in correctly even if it's `95` (two digits instead of three).

Comment: Would like to say that this did exactly what I needed. Thanks! Occasionally I'm just not sure what to Google, but this has solved my problem. Much appreciated. Hopefully someone with more reputation than I will upvote you.